# error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, ND4J in scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, math, nd4j

I am trying to create an `INDArray` of zeros with the following code:

```
var testArray = Nd4j.zeros(3,4)
```

However I got the following error:

```
<console>:71: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method zeros in object Nd4j of type (x$1: Int*)org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray
and  method zeros in object Nd4j of type (x$1: Long, x$2: Long)org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray
match argument types (Int,Int)
       var testArray = Nd4j.zeros(3,4)
```

Any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest methods would be to explicitly declare parameters as long:

```
var testArray = Nd4j.zeros(3L, 4L)
```

Comment: @GermanFarinas no problem, consider marking the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this in later versions of ND4S when calling `arr.getDouble`, this is solved by explicitly turning your variables to long, e.g `arr.getDouble(0L)`